# Hybrid View for google map view

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

I am working with map view in my android app. I want to use hybrid view. But i am not finding any way through. In iphone app its a simple one line code. Whats wrong with android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android too, it's one line :

> [`setSatellite()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setSatellite%28boolean%29)
>
> Sets the map mode to "satellite" mode, loading tiles of aerial imagery with roads and names superimposed.

Hybrid is basically satellite imagery with roads and names. You can add more options like [Traffic](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setTraffic%28boolean%29) data or [Street-View](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setStreetView%28boolean%29) information too.

Comment: if this gives hybrid mode. then how can i have purely satellite mode

Comment: and btw Traffic and Street views are restricted to only few countries, why is it so

Comment: That is seems, is not supported. The restriction is to save costs and some countries have laws against StreetView, in some places work is in progress. Right now only US, UK, Europe and some major cities are covered.

Comment: can i have only satellite mode